# Stop an Azure Function App by using Runbook

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have an Azure Function app running which I need to stop and start on a schedule.
tried to automate it by Azure Automation Account using Runbook with PowerShell script.

Will a single line of command work?

I tried below.

```
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name MyFUNCTION_APP_NAME -ResourceGroupName MyRESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -AppSetting @{"AzureWebJobs.MyFunctionName.Disabled" = "true"}
```

upon running it throws error -

```
Failed
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Do I have to pass the name of the function app as a variable/parameter or something? Or just one line above is all that is needed?

Tried different syntaxes found around internet but none worked.

Comment: Why don't you call the direct cmdlet meant to STOP the function app, [Stop-AzFunctionApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.functions/stop-azfunctionapp?view=azps-9.2.0)

Comment: Doesnt work aswell. 


`Stop-AzFunctionApp -Name MyAppName -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName -Force`


Gives same error -  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

The expected values are the name of the function and RG Name which I provided. Don't understand what I'm missing

Comment: Before executing this cmdlet, have you authenticated in the powershell in one of the way described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Anand Sowmithiran for the comment.

When I run the below commands Iam able to Stop the Azure Function.

```cs
Get-AzFunctionApp -Name FuncAppName -ResourceGroupName YourRGGroupName| Stop-AzFunctionApp -Force
```

***OR***

```cs
Stop-AzFunctionApp -Name FunctionApp2Jan -ResourceGroupName YourRGGroupName -Force
```

***Before Running the command :***

[image]

***After running the Stop Command :***

[image]

- I am able to run the command which you are trying to execute.

> ```cs
>  Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name FunctionApp2Jan ->ResourceGroupName YourRGName -AppSetting >{"AzureWebJobs.MyFunctionName.Disabled" = "true"}
> ```

[image]

***App Settings in Configuration Section :***

[image]